# html form: action page doesn't see element added dinamically with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I wrote a code to add dinamically elements in a form with js. when i submit data, action page says that index of this element are undefined
I have this form:

```
    <form action="testRicetta.php" method= "POST" >
     [...]
     <ul id ="passi" >
        <li id ="li_passo0">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25">
            <label for="descrizione">Passo 0</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-75">
            <textarea id="passo0" name="passo0" placeholder="Descrivi 
            il passo" style="height:100px" required ></textarea>
            <input type="file" id="immagine_0" name="immagine" >
          </div>
        </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
<button id="addMore" >Aggiungi passo</button>
```

This is the js code where appear the listener of button #addMore

```
   var passi = 1;
   $(function() {
   $("#addMore").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#passi").append(`<li id ="li_passo"`+passi+`>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="passo"`+passi+`>Passo `+passi+`</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <textarea id="passo"`+passi+` name="passo"`+passi+` 
              placeholder="Descrivi il passo" style="height:100px" 
            required ></textarea>
                <input type="file" id="immagine_"`+passi+` 
             name="immagine" >
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>`);

        passi++;
    },
    $('.sel').chosen());
     })
```

action page:

```
   echo $_POST{passo0];
   echo $_POST{passo1];
```

Result:

```
         Notice: Undefined index: passo1
```

Furthermore, is possibile read data in a loop? i tried this

```
     for($i = 0; isset($_POST['passo'+$i]);$i++)
         echo $_POST['passo'+$i];
```

but i get this error:

```
   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in (the loop)
```

So how can i read this data, and how can do it with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your adding the new field, you are concatenating the `passi` variable value outside the of name `name="passo"'+passi+'`, it should be `name="passo'+passi+'"`.

Try:

```
   var passi = 1;
   $(function() {
   $("#addMore").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#passi").append('<li id ="li_passo"'+passi+'>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="passo"'+passi+'>Passo '+passi+'</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <textarea id="passo"'+passi+' name="passo'+passi+'" 
              placeholder="Descrivi il passo" style="height:100px" 
            required ></textarea>
                <input type="file" id="immagine_"'+passi+' 
             name="immagine" >
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>');

        passi++;
    },
    $('.sel').chosen());
     })
```

And then:

```
   echo $_POST[passo0];
   echo $_POST[passo1];
```